# Three-way join table with sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, join

I'm trying to implement the sr27 database using Sequelize models. The sr27 database has a join table that connects Foods with Nutrients and Data Sources. The sr27 data has multiple entries with the same Food ID and Nutrient ID but a different Data Source ID to go make each row unique. Basically values can be repeated, but each row much be unique by the three columns combined.

I attempted to re-create this by using two belongsToMany associations on each of the three types (two associations to link each of the other two types to a given type). I used the 'through' key to specify the same join table for all three of these.

My join table ends up only having two columns though, neglecting to add a Food ID column.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? What am I missing?